# foreach for array of array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to add elements in Array of Array as

```
$categoryTreeStructure[$grantCategoryName][$parentCategoryName][$subCategoryText]['text'] =$subCategoryText;
// GET CHILD CATEGORY URL
$categoryTreeStructure[$grantCategoryName][$parentCategoryName][$subCategoryText]['url'] = $childPageLink;
```

I tried to loop through each category as

```
foreach($categoryTreeStructure as $categoryName => $subCategories ){
echo $categoryName."<br>";
}
```

I am getting blank in `$categoryName`.
I need to loop through each category how can I do this?

Comment: edit your questio with the result of `var_dump($categoryTreeStructure);`

Comment: Just to be clear you want to loop this array to get `['text']` and `['url']` back right?

Comment: please paste a bigger part of your code, maybe the full loop. Try to enable error displays too (`ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL)`). From what we can see, I suppose that `$grantCategoryName` is always blank or undefined (maybe upper/lowercase variable name differs in your code)

Comment: If you are lost in those multiple dimension, you can try to create a first "layer" of `for each` loop, then doing a `print_r($myvar)` to see what type your variable is. If it is an array again, do another loop for this variable, etc... until you get what you want.  But seeing the structure of your array, I think 3 loop could be perfect to reach 'text' or 'url' values.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($categoryTreeStructure as $categoryName => $subCategories ){
 foreach($subCategories as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $subkey => $subval){
        echo $subval['text'] . "<br>";
        echo $subval['url'];
    }
 }
}
```

The only way I can see it working is if you use nested loops

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the second dimension of your array isn't target. You array look like so :

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [] => Array
                (
                    [foo] => Array
                        (
                            [text] => foo
                            [url] => Bar
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

If you want to accept you data you will nice a foreach like this :

```
foreach($categoryTreeStructure[$parentCategoryName] as $categoryName ){
        print_r($categoryName);
}
```

This will output :

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [text] => foo
            [url] => Bar
        )

)
```

But in your exemple you wanted the direct text so :

```
foreach($categoryTreeStructure[$grantCategoryName][$parentCategoryName][$subCategoryText] as $categoryName ){
        echo $categoryName;

}
```

This will output :

```
foo
Bar
```

This is the answer for your exemple as your exemple only seen to loop in the last array but if you have multiple `subCategoryText` as expected you will need to have nested loop like @Rossco pointed out :

```
foreach($categoryTreeStructure as $categoryName => $subCategories ){
 foreach($subCategories as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $subkey => $subval){
        echo $subval['text'] . "<br>";
        echo $subval['url'];
    }
 }
}
```